# Python dictionary counter positions change

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, collections

So i'm trying to count the most repeated values in an text file. By using the `Counter` method it returns exaclty what im looking for

## file.txt

```
12334
99965
99965
44144
99965
00000
44144
```

## script.py

```
pArray=[]
with open("file.txt") as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
             pArray.append((line.split('\n'))[0])
        dictn = Counter(pArray)
        print(dictn)
        for key, value in dictn.items():
                print("KEY",key)    
                print("VALUE",value)
        print(dictn)
```

## OUTPUT

```
Counter({'99965': 3, '44144': 2, '12334': 1, '00000': 1})
KEY 12334
VALUE 1
KEY 99965
VALUE 3
KEY 44144
VALUE 2
KEY 00000
VALUE 1
['12334', '99965', '44144', '00000']
```

But as you can see the output of the final array is not in the same order as the dictionary 
(`value` should be in descending order)

I am expecting an output like

```
 ['99965', '44144', '12334', '00000']
```

I also tried `list(dictn.keys())` but i got the same output :/  
Why is the order changing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Dictionaries **have no order** in Python, I am afraid you'll have to sort it once creating a list or something of that approach...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to iterate over a collections.Counter() instance in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037005/pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-collections-counter-instance-in-descending-orde)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects), we see that `Counter` objects: are "unordered collections" - much like `dictionaries`, (in-fact they are a sub-class). So this means that iterating over `.items()` won't give the elements in order of size.

However, we can simply use [`.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) which returns a *list* of *tuples* - each containing an element and its count. The most important thing being that it is in order.

So all we need to do is use a `list-comprehension` to extract the first element of each *tuple* in the *list* returned. That can be done with:

```
[t[0] for t in dictn.most_common()]
```

which gave:

```
['99965', '44144', '12334', '00000']
```

but could also give the following as the counts for `'12334'` and `'00000'` are the same. This is unavoidable due to the nature of how dictionaries (and Counters) work. But if this is important, just let me know and I can update the answer.

```
['99965', '44144', '00000', '12334']
```

---

*Note that not all of your code needs to be inside the `with` statement, once you have created `pArray`, you can exit the `with` statement. Also, basic Python uses `lists`, **not** `arrays`!*

Comment: Having the same values wont be an issue. Thanks this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `Key`, `Value` pairs you can do

```
for key in reversed(sorted(dictn)):
    print("KEY: {0}, VALUE: {1}".format(key, dictn[key]))
```

Comment: It does, python dictionaries retrieve keys by default, which is exactly the same thing as dictn.keys() in a loop. Nonetheless if the ordering is regarded to each item value, then yes that code is improper.