# How to know the last time a product has been updated MongoD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, robo3t

I am working on a project where I want to filter by the products that hasn't been updated in 2 months or a determinated date.(that don't have a new item price in the last 2 months or any other date I want to)
I want to do the script in python.

All my db are json that follow this estructure:

And to access it i do mongo_client[db_name][coll_name] and then i normally use .find() or .aggregate()

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6188f511091533324af78fbf"),
    "market" : "x",
    "product" : "apple",
    "item_price_history" : [ 
        {
            "item_price" : 219.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-04-08T15:30:43.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "item_price" : 248.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-04-22T08:02:28.000Z")
}
```

Do you have any idea of how can I do that? I use the lastest version of Python and Robo 3T-1.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried sorting `item_price_history`(which is a list of dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser

list_to_sort = {
     "market" : "x",
     "product" : "apple",
     "item_price_history" : [
         {
             "item_price" : 219.0,
             "date" : "2021-04-08T15:30:43.000Z"
         },
         {
             "item_price" : 248.0,
             "date" : "2021-04-22T08:02:28.000Z"
         }]
}

candidates = list_to_sort.values()

for item in candidates:
    if isinstance(item,list):
        list_to_sort = item



def myfunc(item):
    time = dateutil.parser.parse(item["date"])
    return time.timestamp()

list_to_sort.sort(key=myfunc)
print(list_to_sort)
```

this will sort the list based on custom function `myfunc`

Comment: The problem i have is that my db is stored in [mongo_db][db_name][coll_name]. Being db_name the name of the db and coll_name the exact file. So i cannot use list_to_sort like this. Anyway thank you I will try to implement this but if you have any other suggestion let me know please. With your code I get this error: "TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to "
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'sort' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists."

Comment: does this work?, it will if you don't have other lists in the original object

Comment: still not working, having same error

Comment: I checked, for a list instead of checking for key for the list, since, your comment mentioned, this key can change. However if you are getting the error, as mentioned in your comment, it is possible to extract the list only by checking for list inside the object or creating a list by looping over values of object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037005/pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-collections-counter-instance-in-descending-orde

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the data in the `item_price_history` to check when that field was last updated. But you don't seem to have a way to track when the other field were updated.

Going forward, you could try adding a pre-save hooks to store the last updated datetime if you're using an ODM like [MongoEngine](https://docs.mongoengine.org/index.html).

Refer `pre_save` method [here](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html).

Comment: And do you know how I will know if any field has been updated since a determinated date? This also will work for me probably for the moment. Thank you

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use the `item_price_history` for now to get the data you want using the `filter` method. 
But if you do add the `pre_save` hook, you can automatically update the field you want. So you can add a hook that will set the `updated_at` field to the current timestamp. This way, any time a document is updated, the `updated_at` field will also get updated. You can then use it to filter the documents you want as part of the query itself.